# Need assistance in ansible playbook for compressing files and excluding files based on certain condition

Tags: ansible, compression

I have created an ansible playbook which finds files older than 7 days ,trying to exclude
files from particular directory or already zipped but not able to exclude.

tasks:

```
 - name : Find files ending with extensions
  become: true
  find:
   path:
   - /home/test/replicate/vol/gunnsc01/prod/scoreout
   recurse: yes
   file_type: any
   age: 7d
   age_stamp: mtime
   excludes: "delete"
  register: output

- name: archive the files
  become: yes
  archive:
    remove: yes
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ item.path }}-{{ansible_date_time.date.replace('-','')}}.gz"
    format: zip
  with_items: "{{ output.files }}"
```

I am not able to exclude specific directory ,I have tried exclude,excludes,exclude_path,exclude_paths and exclude_patterns

however I am not able to exclude the files under the directory delete

Comment: it is unclear whether you need to create zip archives or directories, or a gzipped backup for each file (ie. `file_type: any` and `format: zip` and `dest: [...].gz`)

Comment: I need to compress (zip,tar) files which are older than 7 days also want to exclude files in particular directory and already zipped files.

eg: If I have two directories in a path directory1 and directory2 and directory 1 contains file1 and file2.gz and directory 2 contains files
file3 and file4.gz where all the files are older than 7 days ,I want to exclude for example "directory 2" from completley getting archived 
and for "directory 1" even the file file2.gz is already more than 7 days it should not get zipped again.